# MssqlHook airflow connection

Tags: airflow

I am new to using airflow and what I need to do is to use MssqlHook but I do not know how. What elements should I give in the constructor?

I have a connection in airflow with name connection_test.

I do not fully understand the attributes in the class:

```
class MsSqlHook(DbApiHook):
    """
    Interact with Microsoft SQL Server.
    """

    conn_name_attr = 'mssql_conn_id'
    default_conn_name = 'mssql_default'
    supports_autocommit = True
```

I have the following code:

```
sqlhook=MsSqlHook(connection_test)
sqlhook.get_conn()
```

And when I do this the error is **Connection failed for unknown reason**.

How should I do in order to make it work with the airflow connection ?

What I need is to call function .get_conn() for the MsSqlHook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the standard examples of Airflow.

https://github.com/gtoonstra/etl-with-airflow/blob/master/examples/mssql-example/dags/mssql_bcp_example.py

E.g.:

```
t1 = MsSqlImportOperator(task_id='import_data',
                         table_name='test.test',
                         generate_synth_data=generate_synth_data,
                         mssql_conn_id='mssql',
                         dag=dag)
```

**EDIT**

```
hook = MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id="my_mssql_conn")
hook.run(sql)
```

You need to provide the connection defined in Connections. Also if using Hooks looking in the respective Operators usually yields some information about usage. This code is from the MSSQLOperator.

Comment: I do not want to use MsSqlOperator, just the MsSqlHook in a python script.

Comment: I tried as you said, but tge error is still the same.Is there a way to print the airflow connection details inside the script to see what connection is being used and with what credentials?

Comment: @AndreeaA What does that mean, did you copy the code? Did you create a mssql connection? You need to provide a string as a name.

Comment: Note, you may need to set `autocommit=True` when calling the operator or the hook.

Comment: and for reference, there is no `MsSqlImportOperator` in the standard version of Airflow. That's a custom operator someone built.