# What to add in a docker image for the airflow environment if we need the DAG to connect to a sql server? And what will be the code for the connection?

Tags: sql-server, docker, airflow

I want to connect to SQL server using my DAG in the airflow environment, what all libraries should I include in my docker image so that it creates the environment to connect the sql server.

My docker image includes:
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TERM linux

Answer (score 0):

I believe including `mssql` among the list of [Airflow `extras`](https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html) should suffice

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[mssql]'
```

---

**EDIT-1**
*responding to query raised in comments*

[image]

Assuming you are

- Creating an [Airflow `Connection`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=connection#connections) (webUI or otherwise)
- Using an [Airflow `Hook`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=connection#hooks), namely [`MsSqlHook`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/mssql_hook.py)

Airflow will take care of generating the connection string for you

- It picks [`conn_type`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/connection.py#L91) from the category `Microsoft SQL Server`
- It [creates](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py#L71) the properly formatted endpoint URI
- And [`DbApiHook`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py) that extends `MsSQLHook` also offers methods like [`get_records()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py#L94)

As for example you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51860272/3679900)

Comment: if I install this what will be my connection string then ? Can you share a sample code? I have already did a pip install pymssql but when I use my connection string it shows service adapter not found.

Comment: Tried this but it shows service adapater not found while connecting to the sql server.